# some strings isn't translated in a fragment

Tags: android

I'm developing an application, the application using strings for multi-language support.
but when I'm  using strings inside a fragment, in the application appears always in English.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/string_key"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Hi Abdelali, welcome to StackOverflow! Have you checked and verified that the device that you're testing the application on has been set to use a different language in the device's settings?

Comment: thank u Eric for your response.
no, because some other strings translated correctly the problem just in strings that I used in fragments.